# Accessing two variables from href using $_GET['var']

Tags: php

I'm trying out PHP for the first time and I'm having difficulties passing a `<select>` value.

Here's the  code :

```
<select name="progress">
    <option value="" disabled selected><?php echo $row['percent']; ?> </option>
    <option value="50%">50%</option>
    <option value="75%">75%</option>
    <option value="100%">100%</option>
</select>
```

So I was trying to pass it with this code (based on some posts, it is how to do it) :

```
<a href="jobstatus.php?ID=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&PR=<?php echo $_POST["progress"]; ?>"> Update</a>
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the values on jobstatus.php :

```
$id = $_GET['ID'];
$pr = $_GET['PR'];
$sql = "UPDATE FROM status SET percent = '$pr' WHERE id = '$id'";
```

It does not update my database, hence I'm being redirected to my error page.

Any links for tutorial and correct ways of coding this would be much appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: `disabled selected`. Hmm.

Comment: `"UPDATE status SET percent = '$pr' WHERE id = '$id'"` if status is the name of table.

Comment: Hi Josh, why is your % disabled selected? you should also have your PHP echo code inside the option value="<?php ... ?>"

Comment: @Niet, basically this is how I want it to look like - 
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> 
I don't think there's any problem with that value for the first option.

Comment: PHP runs server-side, not client-side. It has no way to know what the value of your select box is until you have submitted your form. What you probably want to be doing is getting the value of the select box using Javascript. You should give the `select` element an `id` attribute and then access the value using something like `document.getElementById("someID").value`. That being said, an alternative way to do it would probably be to have a hidden input with `name='ID'` and then just post your form to `jobstatus.php`

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ, I was able to pass the value of the select box on one of my pages. However, I only passed one variable which was the select value. So I was thinking that there's something wrong with my syntax for passing 2 variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE FROM` is incorrect. `UPDATE` is all you need.

Also obligatory xkcd reference
[image: xkcd]

Comment: I was able to update my database table, but I'm getting this error "Undefined index: progre" under the updated column.

Comment: My bad, "progress" was cut. I thought it was some kind of an error.